# Fragments are removed from back stack without reason

Tags: android, android-fragments

Ok, I've stated that fragments are removed without reason. It seems to me, like this, but sureley there is a reason I don't know about. Please help me find it.

I got the `FragmentActivity` which contains `TabHost`, with 5 tabs. `TabHost` has a `onTabChangedListener` like this (nothing complicated here, just a case with copied code):

```
new OnTabChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {
                LiveTabFragment fragment = null;
                int viewHolder = -1;
                switch (tabHost.getCurrentTab()) {
                case TAB_ABOUT:
                    fragment = (LiveAboutFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(LiveAboutFragment.class.getSimpleName());
                    if (fragment == null) fragment = new LiveAboutFragment();
                    viewHolder = R.id.live_tab_about;
                    break;
                case TAB_EVENTS:
                    fragment = (LiveEventsFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(LiveEventsFragment.class.getSimpleName());
                    if (fragment == null) fragment = new LiveEventsFragment();
                    viewHolder = R.id.live_tab_events;
                    break;
                case TAB_PLAYERS:
                    fragment = (LivePlayersFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(LivePlayersFragment.class.getSimpleName());
                    if (fragment == null) fragment = new LivePlayersFragment();
                    viewHolder = R.id.live_tab_players;
                    break;
                case TAB_LEGEND:
                    fragment = (LiveLegendFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(LiveLegendFragment.class.getSimpleName());
                    if (fragment == null) fragment = new LiveLegendFragment();
                    viewHolder = R.id.live_tab_legend;
                    break;
                case TAB_CHAT:
                    fragment = (LiveChatFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(LiveChatFragment.class.getSimpleName());
                    if (fragment == null) fragment = new LiveChatFragment();
                    viewHolder = R.id.live_tab_chat;
                    break;
                }

                if (fragment != null) injectInnerFragment(fragment, viewHolder, false);
            }
        }
```

Here is an `injectInnerFragment` method:

```
public void injectInnerFragment(AaFragment fragment, int viewHolderId, boolean addToBackStack) {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

    if (fragment.isAdded()) {
        transaction.replace(viewHolderId, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
        if (addToBackStack) transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    } else {
        transaction.add(viewHolderId, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
        if (addToBackStack) transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }       
}
```

**Now the problem:**
When I click on tab for thr first time fragment is beeing created (`onCreate` is called) which is normal. In most cases second clicking on already created tab fragment doesn't call fragment's`onCreate` which is what I wanted. Thats why I'm trying to find fragment if `FragmentManager` first.

There are two cases it doesn't work, and previously created fragment is created again, which is not efficient for me. The cases are:

- if I click on any tab, then on TAB_ABOUT, then clicking again on any tab causes it's recreating ("any tab fragment" is not found in `FragmentManager`)
- if I click on any tab, then on TAB_CHAT, then clicking again on any tab causes it's recreating ("any tab fragment" is not found in `FragmentManager`)

What kind of sorcery is this? Is it some automatic memory freeing, dependant on fragment "weight"? Maybe I should store all data I don't want reload each time fragment is created on Activity instead?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your following code :

```
    transaction.replace(viewHolderId, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

try with :

```
     transaction.add(viewHolderId, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

Comment: but won't that be adding same fragments to backstack if I open them couple of times?

Comment: so whats the issue then ?

Comment: issue is that is causes: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added:

Comment: modified inject method, but fragments still recreated

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by modyfing inject method:

```
public void injectInnerFragment(AaFragment fragment, int viewHolderId, boolean addToBackStack) {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

    if (fragment.isAdded()) {
        transaction.attach(fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    } else {
        transaction.add(viewHolderId, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
        if (addToBackStack) transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }       
}
```